# Magical Record KVO on entity count

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Is it possible to watch a particular entity (specifically the count of the entity) and run a method if it changes?

I'm using `Magical Data` and `Core Data`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. MagicalRecord does not inhibit an existing core data functionality. KVO is built into core data and you should be able to observe property changes just fine

Comment: Ah, I didn't know CoreData provided KVO on count. How can I set this up?

Comment: Count is not a property you can observe. You proabLy want to set up,an nsfetchedresultscontroller and responds to new objects matching your predicate